# Randomly Select File and Move Error

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I'm trying to get this batch code to randomly select a file from a specific folder and then move it to another folder, however, I get an error that states: "system cannot find the path specified." Anyone know what is causing this?

```
if not exist "%userprofile%\Documents\asdf.txt" (
  @echo off
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  cd %userprofile%\Dropbox\
  set n=0
  for %%f in (*.*) do (
    set /A n+=1
    set "file[!n!]=%%f"
  )
  set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
  copy "!file[%rand%]!" %userprofile%\documents
)
```

Comment: You're **set**ing **rand** inside an **if** not exist block but not delaying it's expansion. The easiest way to fix it however is to take all of that code out of the if not exist block and just start with `if exist "%user... goto...`

Comment: `dir ~\Dropbox -File |Get-Random |Copy-Item ~\Documents`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Better use gci than dir , that irritates people unused to Powershell.

Comment: Instead off your formula I'd start with ´0` by moving the set /A n+=1 behind `set "file[!n!]=%%f` and then do `Set /A "rand=!random! %% n"`